# Python - Beautiful soup - table

Tags: python, algorithm, beautifulsoup

I have the table below. I would like to scrape this table to have in output format a dictionary :

```html
<h3>TITRE PRINCIPAL</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Titre 1</th>
        <th>Titre 2</th>
        <th>Titre 3</th>
        <th>Titre 4</th>
        <th>Titre 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valeur A</td>
        <td>Valeur B</td>
        <td>Valeur C</td>
        <td>Valeur D</td>
        <td>Valeur E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valeur F</td>
        <td>Valeur G</td>
        <td>Valeur H</td>
        <td>Valeur I</td>
        <td>Valeur J</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valeur K</td>
        <td>Valeur L</td>
        <td>Valeur M</td>
        <td>Valeur N</td>
        <td>Valeur O</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

OUTPUT :

```python
{
    'Valeur A': ['Valeur B', 'Valeur C', 'Valeur D', 'Valeur E'],
    'Valeur F': ['Valeur G', 'Valeur H', 'Valeur I', 'Valeur J'],
    'Valeur K': ['Valeur L', 'Valeur M', 'Valeur N', 'Valeur O']
}
```

I'm doing this :

```python
soup = BeautifulSoup(fichier_html, "html.parser")
for td in tr.findChildren():
```

I know that `td.text` will give me the string contained in td but I can't organize my code to get what I want

Could someone help me?

Comment: That code snippet is not a valid python code. The body of the `for loop` is missing.

Comment: Also, read this [Why Can Someone Help Me Is Not An Actual Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `html_doc` is your HTML code from the question, then:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

trs = soup.select("tr:has(td)")
out = {tr.td.text: [td.text for td in tr.select("td")[1:]] for tr in trs}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "Valeur A": ["Valeur B", "Valeur C", "Valeur D", "Valeur E"],
    "Valeur F": ["Valeur G", "Valeur H", "Valeur I", "Valeur J"],
    "Valeur K": ["Valeur L", "Valeur M", "Valeur N", "Valeur O"],
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will study this solution for a good compréhension. The result is correct.